# Bash: grep pattern from command output

Tags: bash, unix, grep, pipe

I'm really new with bash, but it's one of the subjects on school. One of the exercises was:

**Give the line number of the file "/etc/passwd" where the information about your own login is.**

Suppose `USERNAME` is my own login ID, I was able to do it perfectly in this way:

```
 cat /etc/passwd -n | grep USERNAME | cut -f1
```

Which simply gave the line number required (there may be a more optimised way). I wondered however, if there was a way to make the command more general so that it uses the output of `whoami` to represent the grep pattern, **without scripting or using a variable**. In other words, to keep it an easy-to-read one-line command, like so:

```
 cat /etc/passwd -n | grep (whoami) | cut -f1
```

Sorry if this is a really noob question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
cat /etc/passwd -n | grep `whoami` | cut -f1
```

Surrounding a command in ` marks makes it execute the command and send the output into the command it's wrapped in.

Comment: Without anchoring, this can produce false matches if your login name matches elsewhere on the line.  I used to have a short login name on a local system which happened to match (a substring of) "System Operator" so some stupid software thought I was `root` when I wasn't.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this with a single `awk` invocation:

```
awk -v me=$(whoami) -F: '$1==me{print NR}' /etc/passwd
```

In more detail:

- the `-v` creates an `awk` variable called `me` and populates it with your user name.
- the `-F` sets the field separator to `:` as befits the password file.
- the `$1==me` only selects lines where the first field matches your user name.
- the `print` outputs the record number (line).

Comment: thanks for the great explanation, but for now it seems to advanced for me to build up commands like that myself :)

Comment: @Mario: the sooner you start learning, the sooner you'll be able to charge exorbitant rates for your development services :-)

Answer (score 13):

Check command substitution in the `bash` man page.

You can you back ticks ``` `` ``` or `$()` , and personally I prefer the latter.

So for your question:

```
grep -n -e $(whoami) /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d :
```

will substitute the output of `whoami` as the argument for the `-e` flag of the `grep` command and the output of the whole command will be line number in `/etc/passwd` of the running user.

Comment: +1 because it works, but Lynn's answer is more clear to read (at least to a beginner like me :)) but I like that you pointed out I should use the -n switch of grep to make it shorter.

Comment: +1, I prefer the `$()` construct as well, simply because it's so much easier to nest.