# How to get only a list of primary key values in dynamoDB using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

I want to get a list of primary key 'values' from DynamoDB, and the the primary key looks like this:

```
{
  "primary_key": "value1",
  "other_elements": "element1"
},
{
  "primary_key": "value2",
  "other_elements": "element2"
},
...
{
  "primary_key": "valueN",
  "other_elements": "elementN"
}
```

What I want to get is just a list of "primary_key" values, which will be like:

```
value1
value2
...
valueN
```

I tried the following:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name "table_name" 
--select SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES 
--attributes-to-get "primary_key_name"
```

But it prints all table descriptions, not only those values. 
How can I extract only those values using cli?

Would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `--attributes-to-get` is a legacy parameter (as stated here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html#options). According to that documentation, you want to use `--projection-expression` instead.

As a result, your command would look something like this:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name "table_name" 
--select SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES 
--projection-expression "primary_key_name"
```

The output will not be formatted the way you want, though. I would suggest using `grep` and/or possibly `awk` to only print the value of the primary key. The answer to the following question will help with that: [Bash: grep pattern from command output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280941/bash-grep-pattern-from-command-output).

Comment: Thank you. Though your command is the same as the one I wrote in the question, I understand your answer. Thank you for response!

Comment: Glad this was helpful! I realized that I made a typo in the command, where I wrote `--attributed-to-get` instead of `----project-expression`. My bad! I edited my answer. Did you try running that version of the command? Let me know if you need further assistance with `grep` and `awk`. If you share the output you get from DynamoDB, I can help you single out the primary key.

Comment: Yes, '----project-expression' worked for me. Appreciate it!